# IPTables: Redirect Requests From Host Machine to Docker Container in a Virtual Machine

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, docker, virtualbox

First, let me explain my setup: I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed in a virtual machine on a macOS. In the VirtualBox settings, I created a NAT network and I gave Ubuntu this IP address: `192.168.56.101`. Inside Ubuntu, I have Docker installed. I created a Docker container that runs a python server which listens on `127.0.0.1:5001`. The Docker file exposes the port `5001` so that it is reachable from the outside. I also added the following iptable rules:

```
IPT=/bin/iptables
$IPT -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPT -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPT -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth1 --dport 5001 -d 192.168.56.101 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:5001
```

Now, when I try to connect to it either from the host machine or from Ubuntu, it says connection refused. Can anyone tell me what's the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by adding this rule:

```
$IPT -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 5001 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:5001
```